# Read file without disk caching in Java

Tags: java, file, caching, machine-learning, read-write

I'm training a Neural Network using an extremely large dataset of examples that cannot be fully loaded into RAM all at one time. To train, I read each example from the list of serialized files that comprises the dataset. Windows Disk Caching loads each example into RAM the first time I read it. Normally this would speed up subsequent reads of the same file because RAM is faster than disk, but because my dataset is so large, the file is removed from RAM by the time I loop back around to it so there is no added benefit.

I would like to prevent RAM buildup as much as possible as it slows down all other processes on the machine. Currently the best solution I can think of is disabling disk caching for the files I read. Is this possible in Windows and Java? I am also open to alternative solutions; whatever allows me to iterate over dataset examples without RAM buildup.

UPDATE: The problem I was trying to solve was not caused by RAM buildup from Disk Caching. Instead my slow read speeds were as a result of poor file structuring on my part. Read the last comment in the OP for more details.

Comment: No operating system I know of supports this feature. There is nothing building up which can't be freed trivially as needed. Most of your time is likely to be spent deserializing the data which is likely to be 10 - 100x the cost of reading from disk which in turn is likely to be 100x the cost of copying into RAM.

Comment: Note: Intell PCI SDD drives support user space drivers which allow you to access the drive directly from your application without the OS being involved.

Comment: @PeterLawrey are there any other SSDs that support this? Specifically the Samsung 970 PRO M.2 SSD I just ordered?

Comment: I don't believe so, but I suspect your real problem is very different.  The using disk cache shouldn't be slowing other applications. esp when you have such a fast drive.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's sounds like it's probably right. I assume it has to do with poor JVM heap management on my part.

Comment: I would run flight recorder to get a profile of your application see where it is spending the most time.  Your disk should be able to support 500 MB/s and you can read that as binary in Java, as text you can read about 100 MB/s, and other serialization formats can be worse.

Comment: @PeterLawrey After fiddling around, I found out that 99% of the time spent by the program was retrieving the files from the OS. My file structure was set up such that 1 file contained 1 example (had millions of tiny files). After restructuring my data so that each file contained 1000 examples (took quite a while) my read speeds were ripping fast. Turns out communication from JVM to OS is quite slow especially scaled up like my use case. Thanks for steering me in the right direction!